# trazer dados do banco com Javascript

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Tenho um `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="justificar" data-value="<?= $l->img_id?>">` que ao clicar, preciso que traga um dado do banco de dados, mas não sei como puxar esse dado para a tela.Meu código está em codeigniter, e quando clica no `<a href>` ele chama essa classe:

```
$(document).on('click','.justificar', function(){
var t = $(this);
$.SmartMessageBox({
title : "<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_title"); ?>",
content : "<?= $this->lang->line("view_relat_iten_title_jus"); ?>",
buttons : "[<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_btn_ok"); ?>]",

}, function(ButtonPress, Value) {
if(ButtonPress == "<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_btn_ok"); ?>"){
return 0;
}
});
});
```

Como que eu faço para trazer o dado do banco de dados

Comment: não seria melhor usar o php pra pegar do banco?

Comment: O que você está querendo é fazer uma chamada ajax. Você precisa enviar uma requisição para o servidor e tratá-la no codeigniter para trazer seu dado e então vc recupera o retorno do ajax e exibe o conteúdo

Comment: @RafaelAcioly e como eu posso chamar uma função do controllador no javascript sem usar o window?

Answer (score 1):

O que você está querendo é fazer uma chamada ajax. Você precisa enviar uma requisição para o servidor e tratá-la no codeigniter para trazer seu dado e então vc recupera o retorno do ajax e exibe o conteúdo.

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
  // define o clique do botão
  $("#button").click(function () {
    // faz uma requisição ajax do tipo $_GET
    $.get("/teste/tempo", function (tempo) {
      // atualiza o campo input#tempo com o tempo
      $("#tempo").val(tempo);
    });
  });
});
```

no lado da controller vc cria uma action `tempo` e define o retorno

```
public function tempo()
{
    echo time();
}
```

e assim caminha a humanidade...

---- Edit ----

Dica: seria interessante você separar o php do javascript por questão de separação de responsabilidade, deixar cada um controlar seu próprio espaço.

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui de outra forma. eu criei um class para o botão e no arquivo Javascript coloquei o seguinte código:

```
$(document).on('click', '.just', function (e) {
    logged();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON("Controller/funcao/" + $(this).attr("data-value"), function (j) {
        $('#jus_just').html(j);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

e nesse Controller eu chamei a tabela e o campo que armazena o campo necessário.